# php regex match any number of words

Tags: php, regex

I am new to php regex. I am trying to match any number of words. For eg: A 'person name' can have any number of words, how can I do this?

I tried using `\w+\`, but its matching only 1 word.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bK6wU2/2)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,

```
preg_match('~^\w+(?:\h+\w+)*$~', $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bK6wU2/4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following for matching any number of words separated by whitespace:

```
[\w\s]+
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bK6wU2/5)

PHP:

```
preg_match('~^[\w\s]+$~', $str);
```